# how to simplify scala's function literal like this?

Tags: scala, function-literal

I'm new to scala and trying to write a function literal that check whether a given integer is odd or not.
my first attempt is:

`val isOdd = (x:Int) => (x & 1) == 1`

it works great, and,  since the parameter x only appears once within this function literal, I'm tempted to use the "_" notation to simplify it further, like this:

`val isOdd = ((_:Int) & 1 ) == 1`

however this time the compiler complains :

```
warning: comparing a fresh object using `==' will always yield false
val isOdd = ((_:Int) & 1 ) == 1
```

what does this warning mean? why does the compiler recognize `((_ :Int) & 1)` as fresh object rather than a bitwise operation that results in a value? is there any way to write this function literal using the "_" notation?

Comment: Just use: `val odd = ! even (_:Int)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is basically that Scala needs to tell the difference between

```
val isOdd = ((_:Int) & 1 ) == 1
```

where you want everything to the right of the equals sign to be a lambda, and

```
val result = collection.map( _ + 1 )
```

where you want only the stuff inside the parentheses to be a lambda

Scala has decided that when you use the underscore to create a lambda, that it's going to pick the innermost set of parentheses as the boundaries of that lambda. There's one exception: `(_:Int)` doesn't count as the innermost parentheses because its purpose is only to group they type declaration with the `_` placeholder.

Hence:

```
val isOdd = ((_:Int) & 1 ) == 1
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            this is the lambda

val result = collection.map( _ + 1 )
                            ^^^^^^^
                            this is the lambda

val result = collection.map(( _ + 1) / 2)
                            ^^^^^^^^
                            this is the lambda
                            and the compiler can't infer the type of the _

val result = somemap.map(( _ + 1) / 2 * _)
                         ^^^^^^^^
                         this is an inner lambda with one parameter
                         and the compiler can't infer the type of the _
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         this is an outer lambda with one parameter
```

This last case lets you do things like

```
_.map(_ + 1)
```

and have that get translated into

```
x => x.map( y=> y + 1 )
```

Comment: thx for clarifying the rules about the boundary of the lambda expression!

Answer (score 10):

Only slightly cheating:

```
val isOdd = (_: Int) % 2 == 1
```

:-)

Comment: +1 It's not cheating. In fact, I maintain that using an `&` for this is premature optimization. The `%` form is clearer, and any compiler (or maybe the JIT) worth it's salt will see `% 2` and change it to `& 1` if it's actually faster in that operating environment.

Comment: I agree that in general we should leave this sort of optimizations to compilers; but here i actually want to understand the rationale behind this lambda thing. again thx for clarifying the parentheses rule regarding lambda :)

Comment: @KenBloom I would maintain that using the best algorithm for a job isn't premature optimization, it's just good programming, and I get tired of people using this justification for writing slow code (generally speaking, this is a micro-example where the difference is probably negligible).  That you can accomplish it more elegantly with another mechanism has everything to do with style, and nothing to do with optimization.

Comment: Just be aware this doesn't work for negative numbers, whereas `&` does.

Answer (score 7):

There you go:

```
val isOdd = ((_: Int) & 1) andThen (1 ==)
```

Answer (score 2):

What Scala is doing is this:

- it sees `((_:Int) & 1 )` and creates an object of type `(Int) => Int`, that is, a function.
- it then applies the comparison operator `==` to compare this function to the value 1

A function is not equal to the value 1. Therefore the result is `false`, so your code is equivalent to:

```
val isOdd = false
```

What you could do is create another anonymous function that does the `== 1` part of your computation. This is ugly:

```
val isOdd = ((_: Int) & 1)(_: Int) == 1
```

This is equivalent to the more verbose (and perhaps easier to understand):

```
val isOdd = (x: Int) => 1 == ((_: Int) & 1)(x)
```

Comment: I don't recommend either of these solutions -- they're both more complicated, and they both create an extra, unnecessary lambda. Stick with `val isOdd = (x:Int) => (x & 1) == 1`

Comment: Sure! But the OP asked specifically if there was any way he could write his "isOdd" lambda using only "_". I don't think we are discussing good style here.

Comment: You missed `val isOdd = ((_: Int) & 1) andThen (_ == 1)`. :-)

Comment: Yeah! Fortunately @Debilski posted this one!

Answer (score 1):

A different approach

```
val isOdd = (_:Int).&(1) == 1
```